# How to mount a partition on a LVM logical volume?

Tags: lvm

I had been installing a paravirtualized (PV) guest with Xen on a Logical volume(LV). The installation has seen the LV as a normal hard disk and installed and ext4 and a swap partition on it.

The output of `sudo fdisk -l|grep /dev` is

```
Disk /dev/mapper/vg1/lv1: 40GB
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv1-part1   37G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv1-part2     3  5 Extended
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv1-part3     3 82 swap
```

I can use fdisk to modify those partitions like that

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1
```

But did not manage to mount the partitions anywhere. I tried

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1-part1 /mnt/tmp      // special device does not exist
sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1       /mnt/tmp      // wrong fs type error
sudo mount /dev/vg1/lv1/             /mnt/tmp      // wrong fs type error
sudo mount /dev/vg1/lv1/part1        /mnt/tmp     // special device does not exist
```

So how do I mount the `/dev/mapper/vg1-lv1-part1` partition to `/mnt/tmp`?

Comment: Are those typos in your questions: `/dev/mapper/VG1-lv1-part1` vs. `sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1-part1...` ( unix based systems are sensitive ). There is a slash missing: `sudo mount /devvg1/lv1/part1...`.

Comment: Be aware of case sensitivity!

Comment: @Thomas thanks for spotting the typos. I did change all to lower case. I am aware of the case sensitivity.